# Relation between angular resolution and aperture?

Tags: telescope, fundamental-astronomy, telescope-lens

The angular resolution of a telescope is given by $\frac{1.22\lambda}{D}$.

This should mean that the smaller the aperture D, the higher the angular resolution. But it is exactly the opposite - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the confusion stems from the words used.  "higher" resolution doesn't mean better, it means only bigger objects can be resolved; but we want to be able to resolve small objects, such as the angular distance between a pair of double stars.  So small is better in this situation.

Comment: "Higher resolution" usually *does* mean better. (If you want a plausible way to think about it, "higher" resolution means you can resolve *higher spatial frequencies*, which means smaller angular sizes.)

Comment: Peter Erwin:  well I think that given how the word is commonly used, it’s not a surprise that the OP found the use of “higher” in this context confusing.

Answer (score 6):

The angular resolution only tells you your ability to distinguish ("resolve") two separate points of light. For example, your ability to distinguish the two distinct headlamps on a car from being a single light in the distance.

The angular *magnification* has nothing to do with the angular resolution: it is determined by the focal lengths of your primary and objective, and the eyepiece if applicable.

Answer (score 6):

Your formula is correct. In the absence of instrumental effects or blurring of the atmosphere, it gives (approximately) the minimum *angular separation* between two objects that can be resolved. The larger this is, the *worse* your telescope is. You want the resolution to be *small*.